# 2d dimensions to kilometers javascript

Tags: javascript, dimension

Currently i am working on a project and i need to calculate the distance in kilometer between 2 locations with 2d dimensions.

I would love to see an javascript example

I made a http://jsfiddle.net/ym2sn70u/5/`d f k f` with a example. I like to have a response in KM as a string value. for example 50.9 KM.

i appreciate it

Comment: You probably want to check out the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: I do not think, that the question is to broad. We got a lot of information from the two links to give a short answer. The coordinate system is WSG84 for the nederlands. One possible solution is to take the difference of the points coordinate elements (x and y) -these are the deltas in meters- divide them by 1000 and use pythagoras. Or use coordinate transformation (https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) to lat/lon degress and use haverside provides by e.g. http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_distance.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of 3 algorithms described below (coded in C#, can be converted into Java/Javascript using similar syntax) to find the distance between 2 geographical points on Earth either in miles or km (re: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884183/enRoute-Real-time-NY-City-Bus-Tracking-Web-App):

```
/*****************************************************************************************
Module           :  GIS.cs |Class Lib
Description      :  Calculate distance between two geo-points on surface
*****************************************************************************************
Author           :  Alexander Bell
Copyright        :  2011-2015 Infosoft International Inc
*****************************************************************************************
using System;

namespace BusNY
{
    internal enum UnitSystem { SI = 0, US = 1 }

    internal static class GIS
    {
        #region internal: properties (read-only)
        internal static double EarthRadiusKm { get {return _radiusEarthKM;} }
        internal static double EarthRadiusMiles { get { return _radiusEarthMiles; } }
        internal static double m2km { get { return _m2km; } }
        internal static double Deg2rad { get { return _toRad; } }
        #endregion

        #region private: const
        private const double _radiusEarthMiles = 3959;
        private const double _radiusEarthKM = 6371;
        private const double _m2km = 1.60934;
        private const double _toRad = Math.PI / 180;
        #endregion

        #region Method 1: Haversine algo
        /// <summary>
        /// Distance between two geographic points on surface, km/miles
        /// Haversine formula to calculate
        /// great-circle (orthodromic) distance on Earth
        /// High Accuracy, Medium speed
        /// re: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Lat1">double: 1st point Latitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lon1">double: 1st point Longitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lat2">double: 2nd point Latitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lon2">double: 2nd point Longitude</param>
        /// <returns>double: distance, km/miles</returns>
        internal static double DistanceHaversine(double Lat1,
                                                    double Lon1,
                                                    double Lat2,
                                                    double Lon2,
                                                    UnitSystem UnitSys ){
            try {
                double _radLat1 = Lat1 * _toRad;
                double _radLat2 = Lat2 * _toRad;
                double _dLatHalf = (_radLat2 - _radLat1) / 2;
                double _dLonHalf = Math.PI * (Lon2 - Lon1) / 360;

                // intermediate result
                double _a = Math.Sin(_dLatHalf);
                _a *= _a;

                // intermediate result
                double _b = Math.Sin(_dLonHalf);
                _b *= _b * Math.Cos(_radLat1) * Math.Cos(_radLat2);

                // central angle, aka arc segment angular distance
                double _centralAngle = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(_a + _b), Math.Sqrt(1 - _a - _b));

                // great-circle (orthodromic) distance on Earth between 2 points
                if (UnitSys == UnitSystem.SI)  { return _radiusEarthKM * _centralAngle; }
                else { return _radiusEarthMiles * _centralAngle; }
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Method 2: Spherical Law of Cosines
        /// <summary>
        /// Distance between two geographic points on surface, km/miles
        /// Spherical Law of Cosines formula to calculate
        /// great-circle (orthodromic) distance on Earth;
        /// High Accuracy, Medium speed
        /// re: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Lat1">double: 1st point Latitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lon1">double: 1st point Longitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lat2">double: 2nd point Latitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lon2">double: 2nd point Longitude</param>
        /// <returns>double: distance, km/miles</returns>
        internal static double DistanceSLC(double Lat1,
                                        double Lon1,
                                        double Lat2,
                                        double Lon2,
                                        UnitSystem UnitSys ){
            try {
                double _radLat1 = Lat1 * _toRad;
                double _radLat2 = Lat2 * _toRad;
                double _radLon1 = Lon1 * _toRad;
                double _radLon2 = Lon2 * _toRad;

                // central angle, aka arc segment angular distance
                double _centralAngle = Math.Acos(Math.Sin(_radLat1) * Math.Sin(_radLat2) +
                        Math.Cos(_radLat1) * Math.Cos(_radLat2) * Math.Cos(_radLon2 - _radLon1));

                // great-circle (orthodromic) distance on Earth between 2 points
                if (UnitSys == UnitSystem.SI) { return _radiusEarthKM * _centralAngle; }
                else { return _radiusEarthMiles * _centralAngle; }
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Method 3: Spherical Earth projection
        /// <summary>
        /// Distance between two geographic points on surface, km/miles
        /// Spherical Earth projection to a plane formula (using Pythagorean Theorem)
        /// to calculate great-circle (orthodromic) distance on Earth.
        /// central angle =
        /// Sqrt((_radLat2 - _radLat1)^2 + (Cos((_radLat1 + _radLat2)/2) * (Lon2 - Lon1))^2)
        /// Medium Accuracy, Fast,
        /// relative error less than 0.1% in search area smaller than 250 miles
        /// re: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Lat1">double: 1st point Latitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lon1">double: 1st point Longitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lat2">double: 2nd point Latitude</param>
        /// <param name="Lon2">double: 2nd point Longitude</param>
        /// <returns>double: distance, km/miles</returns>
        public static double DistanceSEP(double Lat1,
                                        double Lon1,
                                        double Lat2,
                                        double Lon2,
                                        UnitSystem UnitSys ){
            try
            {
                double _radLat1 = Lat1 * _toRad;
                double _radLat2 = Lat2 * _toRad;
                double _dLat = (_radLat2 - _radLat1);
                double _dLon = (Lon2 - Lon1) * _toRad;

                double _a = (_dLon) * Math.Cos((_radLat1 + _radLat2) / 2);

                // central angle, aka arc segment angular distance
                double _centralAngle = Math.Sqrt(_a * _a + _dLat * _dLat);

                // great-circle (orthodromic) distance on Earth between 2 points
                if (UnitSys == UnitSystem.SI) { return _radiusEarthKM * _centralAngle; }
                else { return _radiusEarthMiles * _centralAngle; }
            }
            catch { throw; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The third algorithm (Spherical Earth projection) is the fastest/simplest one, providing reasonably good accuracy.

In regards to your edited question: Javascript code snippet seems OK, though Latitude/Longitude format looks different from Geographic coordinate systems (GCS) units of decimal degrees for coordinates used in original 3 algorithms. Here are sample decimal degrees coordinates for some well-known places in Europe/US (using this web app: http://infosoft.biz/geocoder.aspx):

Metropolitan Museum, Lat: 40.779437/Lon: -73.963244

Ακρόπολη Αθηνών, Lat: 37.971532 /Lon: 23.725749

Brandenburger Tor, Lat: 52.516275 /Lon: 13.377704

Champs-Elysées, Lat: 48.869576/Lon: 2.30825

Museo del Prado, Lat: 40.413782/Lon: -3.692127

Cappella Sistina, Lat: 41.902947/Longitude: 12.454484

All 3 functions in C# code snippet have been tested and work fine using this Lat/Lon decimal degrees format with results calculated either in km or miles.

In regards to you additional question (number to string conversion): you can use either num`.toPrecision(N)` or num`.toFixed(N)` javascript functions (plus, `Math.round()` could be also useful in math calculations).

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: user is expecting in JavaScript

Comment: Any of these three algorithmic solutions can be easily converted into Javascript: syntax is rather similar. Regards,

Comment: I and many others can clearly understand that. If the user was someone who never bothered about syntax in programming, he would have not even asked the question with tag "JavaScript example"

Comment: If User decide to use any of these algos and need more assistance then I will respond. Anyway, it's much more easy just to adapt working and thoroughly commented algo written in C# than to write it from the scratch based on general theory found in wiki. Regards,

Comment: If its possible to give me a javascript example i would appreciate it. I never worked with C# so for better understanding i would love to have some javascript example. Regards

Comment: I guess the question is "put on hold as too broad" by other folks, which is actually true - it's indeed too broad. You have to decide which algorithm from 3 listed above you want to use and try to do something on your own: Javascript syntax is very similar to C#. Bring us your code snippet if you have any problem, so we can help. Probably, Method 3: Spherical Earth projection (the simplest one) could be the best fit. Regards,

Comment: I am not really a good calculater but I made a jsfiddle.net/ym2sn70u/5 with a example. I like to have a response in KM as a string value. for example 50.9 KM. i appreciate it

Comment: Javascript snippet seems OK: see the amended answer (you are probably using different coordinate system like WSG84 while this solution works on decimal degree units). I recommend to accept the answer and post another question if you still have any. Best regards,